# Kendo Scheduler not rendering events MVC 5

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, kendo-ui-mvc

It might be an outdated question but why is old kendo MVC version (2016.1.226.545) Scheduler not rendering events on the browser using Microsoft Edge.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<DeploymentScheduleDto>()
            .Name("Deployment")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Date(DateTime.Now)
            .Views(views =>
            {
                views.MonthView();
            })
            .Editable(false)
            .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
                 .DataSource(d => d.Read("Meetings_Read", "VehicleDeployment", new { Area = "Fleet", driverId = 1 })
                 .ServerOperation(true))

                )
```

Controller code

```
 public ActionResult Meetings_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,int driverId)
    {
        var data = _service.GetSchedules(driverId).Select(a => new DeploymentScheduleDto()
        {
            DriverId = driverId,
            IsAllDay = false,
            Description = a.Description,
            Start = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)a.Start, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            End = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)a.End, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Color = "#1962c7",
        }).ToList();
        //string jsonString = "{\"Data\":[{\"RecurrenceRule\":null, \"RecurrenceException\":null,  \"IsAllDay\":true,  \"Start\":\"2022-11-11T10:00:00.000\",  \"StartTimezone\":null,  \"End\":\"2022-11-11T10:00:00.000\",  \"EndTimezone\":null,  \"Title\":\"Test Event\"}],\"Total\":1,\"AggregateResults\":null,\"Errors\":null}";

        //return new ContentResult { Content = jsonString, ContentType = "application/json" };

        return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the result from the browser
[image]
But the scheduler does not render the returned events. I tried to statically return a Json to test if it's the date format but to no avail.

There is an error when selecting a date from scheduler
[image]

Comment: It appears the Scheduler cannot find some template. Are you using templates or external templates? If so make sure they are available and follow the template syntax.

Comment: My mistake was not passing the model Id on the data source results.